# mysqli: Returning the same connection when calling constructor twice like $new_link=false;

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm using mysqli to create a connection to the database, using the OOP approach. Is there a way to make it behave like mysql_connect which got a $new_link=false, making it return the same connection for everyone in this script even if they created a new instance?

This is an example of how I'm connecting:

```
     class DB extends mysqli {

                public function __construct() {
                    $server_params =    $this->server_params; 
                    if (!$server_params) {
                        throw Exception('No server params for server: '.$server);
                    }
                    @parent::__construct($server_params['host'], $server_params['user'], $server_params['pass'], $server_params['db'], $port, $socket);
                    if ($this->connect_errno != 0){
                        throw new Exception($this->connect_error, $this->connect_errno);
                    }                
              }
     }
```

And making two instance is just calling

```
$db = new DB;
```

Twice from different namespaces in the same script.

I'm aware I can create a singelton and/or use dependency injection, but was wondering if this can be done in the connection request directly.

Comment: Yes, it does. Why don't you test it yourself?

Comment: Rephrased question, I actually assumed that was the case, and was wondering if there's any way to 'overcome' this.

Comment: +1 for the proper connection code. Where did you learn that? It is seldom can be seen on Stack Overflow. The only typo you have is a duplicated constructor call

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks, removed the duplication (Copy Paste to stack issue).

Answer (score 0):

It's normally not a good idea to have two different objects embody the same SQL database connection.  If you start a transaction in one instance what happens if you commit in the other?  If they represent different sessions on the same database that's fine, because sessions are isolated from each other (each session can start its own transaction without risking the other session getting into a nonsensical state).  In that case you'd just create new instances for each connection you want open.

```
$db1 = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$db2 = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
```

If you need multiple references to the same connection and session, then all you need to do is this:

```
$db1 = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
$db2 = $db1;
```

Both $db1 and $db2 will refer to the same object and therefore the same connection.

Answer (score -1):

> I was wondering if this can be done in the connection request directly.

Nope, that's impossible.
I see not a much problem with it though.

Answer (score -2):

From (http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

```
Prepending host by p: opens a persistent connection. mysqli_change_user() is automatically called on connections opened from the connection pool.
```

Comment: Persistent connections has nothing to do with creating different connections within the same instance.